# Data loss in onConfigrationChanged for Fragement on android

Tags: android, configuration, screen-orientation

I am developing app with navigation drawer with action bar tab. If the orientation has changed the content should not be lost.

I tried adding an entry to my manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|screenLayout"
```

It's working for TextView values but not working for ImageViews.
I have the images in ListView it will load from a webservice, if orientation has changed the image should not reload from the webservice.

I tried to override this method but I don't know how to persist the data.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Can any one guide me towards a solution?

my adapter full code is here

```
private ArrayList<Blog> blogs = new ArrayList<Blog>();
private ListView listView;
private ReadingsAdapter adapter;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView empty;

public static ReadingsTab newInstance(Category category) {
    ReadingsTab fragment = new ReadingsTab();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("Category", category);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_readings, container,
            false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.reading_tab_progressbar);
    empty = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loadBlog(getActivity());
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

public void loadBlog(final Activity activity) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    MultipartEntity parms = new MultipartEntity();
    try {
        parms.addPart("catid", new StringBody(((Category) getArguments()
                .getSerializable("Category")).getId()));
        Log.d("Category Id",
                ((Category) getArguments().getSerializable("Category"))
                        .getId());
        new JSONParser(getActivity(), Server.FUNC_GET_LOAD_READING,
                new RequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRequestSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        try {
                            if ("success".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonObject
                                    .getString("status"))) {
                                JSONArray data = jsonObject
                                        .getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                    blogs.add(Blog.fromJson(data
                                            .getJSONObject(i)));
                                }
                                adapter = new ReadingsAdapter(activity,
                                        blogs);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            } else {
                                listView.setEmptyView(empty);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRequestFailure(Error error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Helper.failureErrorMessage(getActivity(), error);
                    }
                }).execute(parms);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Blog is a class

```
package com.griffin.android.schoolapp.adapter;
```

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Blog {

```
private String id;
private String title;
private String image;
private String url;

public Blog(String id, String title, String image,String url) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.url = url;
}

public static Blog fromJson(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    return new Blog(object.getString("id"), object.getString("title"),object.getString("image"),
            object.getString("url"));
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

}

adapter is 
       public class ReadingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

```
public ReadingsAdapter(Context context, List<Blog> data) {
    super(context, R.layout.readings_list_item, data);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
}

/**
 * Populate new items in the list.
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.readings_list_item,
                parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    final Blog item = getItem(position);
    final ImageView contentimage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.contentImage);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(item.getTitle());
    final ProgressBar imageloading = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.imageloading);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(item.getImage(), contentimage, new ImageLoadingListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            imageloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            contentimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                FailReason failReason) {
            imageloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            contentimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            imageloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
            contentimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            contentimage.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            imageloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
            contentimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
    contentimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String txt = item.getUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),WebPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", txt);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: you already prevented it from changing its orientation..

Answer (score 1):

You should try Volley: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley It's a networking app for Android. You can use it to cache your loaded images.

A few examples can be found here: https://github.com/PareshMayani/Android-Volley-Example

Comment: Just to add: The first time you use Volley, the image doesn't exist in cache and Volley will download the image from your server. Then when the user rotates the phone the image exists and Volley will use the existing copy. Another (simpler) alternative is Picasso https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|screenLayout"
```

All you do is preventing Android re-call onCreate(), by calling

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

sadly, you do nothing :).
If you're using fragment, you can set the setReinstance to true to save state, remember remove the android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml. It is a bad practice
Or you can save the state in onDestroyView() and save them back in onCreateView() - should check the savedInstance is null or not...
For tasks, I think it is better to keep weak references with activity.

Comment: where i have to give setRetainInstance(true); in onCreateView()??

Comment: Yes, in onCreateView, you can set this. This will prevent the fragment  is created again. But one side effect is that, the orientation layout will not be updated ( if you save your layout in layout-land/layout-port-... because as i know, android will load this automatically in onCreate() )

Comment: i gave like this and its not working 

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_readings, container,
    false);
  setRetainInstance(true);
  listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
  progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView
    .findViewById(R.id.reading_tab_progressbar);
  empty = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  loadBlog(getActivity());
  return rootView;
 }

Comment: @John What is the exception. and loadBlog() function will fill the empty text view? IF you don't mind, could you share us some code snippet.

Comment: The picture here is that: You have a navigation drawer that contain some items ReadingAdapter and the data will be load into ReadingTabs.
If you rotate the screen, the content in the ReadingTabs is missing.
1. i suggest you to write down the flow chart to find out which variable saved the page content. I see that, you call WebPage activity to start browse data when click on an item.
2. In onDestroyView, save the content view into Bunndle, you may be need override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and onCreateView() you fetch the data from savedInstanceState (check null please )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54770/discussion-between-kidnan1991-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a different approach:

1. Create a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) to hold your data (for images store
   the Url)
2. Use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to download the data and insert
   into the ContentProvider
3. Use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) to display the data
   in your fragment/activity
4. To display the images use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) (inside [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html))

---

- Your data will be saved in the local database and when you rotate the
  phone you won't lose it.
- An IntentService runs in a background thread
  independent from the Activity, so rotating the phone won't stop it
- CursorLoader will load the data in a background thread so your UI
  won't be blocked
- Picasso will cache the images the first time they are
  loaded, so after rotation there will be no network call

You can find a working code here: https://github.com/twitter-university/LearningAndroidYamba/tree/master/Yamba-8